# Get data from external website using url in php

Tags: php, html, curl

I want to put on my web application some values from an external website, but it doesn't work.
The url is like this:  http://www.page.it/it/search_s_refoem_AXCDD12.html

AXCDD12 is passed using a form.
I have used curl.

```html
$curl2 = curl_init("http://www.misterauto.it/it/search_s_refoem_".$codice.".html");


curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$html2 = curl_exec($curl2);

if(!empty($curl2)){
 $thispage = new DOMDocument;
 libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
 $thispage->loadHTML($html2);
 libxml_clear_errors();

 $xpath = new DOMXPath($thispage);


 if(substr($codice, 0, 1)=='A'){
   $fornitore = "BLUE PRINT";
   $prezzoMA = $xpath->evaluate('string(//*[@id="p brand10565"]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[2])');
 }else if(substr($codice, 0, 1)=='F'){
   $fornitore = "FERODO";
   $prezzoMA = $xpath->evaluate('string(//*[@id="body"]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[3]/div[1])');
 }else{
   $prezzoMA = $xpath->evaluate('string(//*[@id="p-brand-21"]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[2])');
 }

}
```

when i print the value of $prezzoMA, it shows nothing, but it must show me the price.
I have used the same code for another website changing the xpath and it works, but on this website doesn't work

Comment: Can you show the code of what you have tried so far? We cannot help you if we don't know what is going wrong. Also, that url doesn't work so we can't check why it isn't working.

Comment: $curl2 = curl_init("http://www.mister-auto.it/it/search_s_refoem_".$codice.".html");
 curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            $html2 = curl_exec($curl2);                      
                      if(!empty($curl2)){
                        $thispage = new DOMDocument;
                        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
                        $thispage->loadHTML($html2);
                        libxml_clear_errors();
                        $xpath = new DOMXPath($thispage);
                        echo $prezzoMA;
                      }

Comment: I have put the code

Comment: What is the respose you are getting please post that so that we can help you

Comment: Thanks for your message, i have added it!